# Setting up of Amazon Web Services (AWS) Database and EC2

Tags: sqlite, amazon-web-services

Currently, I have python codes that build machine learning models. The data for these models come from a local SQLite database (my client provides the data to us in S3 bucket, I download them to my machine and push them to the SQLite database). At a very high level, these are 3 steps I perform on my machine:

1. Download the data from S3 and load to SQLite
2. Connect to SQLite using python and perform data cleaning, aggregation, and model building in python
3. Write the results again to the SQLite

Our client has asked us to provide specifications for setting up an Amazon server so that we can run all these processes everyday as an application by click of a button. We planned of providing all the information after implementing the above mentioned end to end steps using our AWS account. I have no prior experience in setting up AWS/ db but want to learn more. These are the following question I have:

1. Can the above process be replicated on AWS? I use python 2.7 and SQLite db
2. We don't use any relationship in SQLite db while reading or writing data (like PK constraints etc.,). So is it better directly to read and write from S3 
   bucket
3. What are the different components on AWS that i need to have? As per my understanding for running the code I need EC2 (provides CPU, processors etc.,) and for storing, reading and writing the data I need a datastorage component. (Sorry, for usage of layman terms, I'm a newbie and trying to learn things)
4. Any things I need to keep in mind? Links for resources that can help me the solution.

Regards,

Eswar

Comment: This question is better asked on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) as it isn't really about programming and more about a system architecture.  In general you can look at [AWS EC2 user data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html) but, again, server fault would be able to give you a more complete answer.

Comment: Thanks. Will add this question to Server Fault.